# Prove that $V = V_1 \oplus V_2$ in the following

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ such that $T^2=1_V$. Define

$V_1 = \left\{v\in V |\ T(v) = v \right\}$, 
$\ V_2 = \left\{v\in V |\ T(v) = -v\right\}$

prove that
$V = V_1 \oplus V_2$

For start, I've shown that $V_1\ ,V2$ are subspace of $V$.
However, I'm stuck trying to show that $\forall \ v\in V,\ v = v_1 + v_2$ where $v_1 \in V1, v_2 \in V_2$.

I know at some point I have to make use of  $T^2=1_V$, but cant figure out how. Any help or insight is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* To prove that $V=V_1+V_2$, we have to prove that for each $v\in V$ there are $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$ such $v=v_1+v_2$. So, take $v\in V$ and consider
$$
v_1 = \dfrac12 (v+T(v))
\quad
v_2 = \dfrac12 (v-T(v))
$$

> Then $v_1\in V_1$, $v_2\in V_2$, and $v=v_1+v_2$.

It remains to prove that $V_1 \cap V_2 = 0$:

> If $v \in V_1 \cap V_2$, then $v=T(v)=-v$ and so $2v=0$.

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do here, but I have one concern is that we are kinda assuming $\forall v_1\in V_1$, is of the form $v_1 = \frac{1}{2}(v + T(v))$ and vice versa for $v_2$. why can we do that in this case ?

Comment: @user2875613, we just have to exhibit $v_1$ and $v_2$ given $v$.

Comment: I see , so the point is we want to show $\forall v\in V$, $v$ can written as SOME sum of 2 vectors from $V_1, V_2$ right ?

Comment: @user2875613, yes.

Comment: I see, thank you for the reply. It really helped my revision